# Функция диалоги

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с проблемой, на сайте есть функция обмена сообщениями, теперь я ее переделываю под диалоги. Необходимо выводить логины, с которыми уже есть сообщения и если нажать на логин, то открывается окно с самим диалогом при этом логины не должны повторятся!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас куда, в `БД` диалоги пишутся? Вы скажите по коду что именно не получается, или вы не понимаете как это организовать?

Comment: я не понимаю как это организовать я сначала пытался как то их из общей массы выделять но запутался ...

Comment: На сколько я понимаю вы хотите блоговый диалог сделать типа комментов? Записываете в `БД` `login` и `коммент` и еще поле добавляете с `id_comment`, потом выносите это все в диалог. Тут должны быть задействованы реляционные связи таблицы (начните с этого).

Comment: а проще нельзя? простейший пример диалогов это вконтакте там по сути то чего я хочу добиться ...

Comment: ну я бы поспорил на счет "простейший" =) вам привели простой пример как это должно выглядеть, проще не будет.

Comment: ну блин ...

Comment: Я зделал!!!!!!!!!